# JavaFX : bad text alignment in TextField

Tags: javafx, textfield

When I set text bigger than size of the `TextField` (with alignment - Center) : I get this:
[image].

When I move the cursor to the right, the position of the line can not be returned to the previous position. You can bring the cursor to the end and then the line will be in the desired form 
[image]

Text shows properly when size is smaller:
[image].

I change `fx-alignment`, `fx-font`, `fx-height`, `fx-width`. Other parameters are default.

I want to find a way to properly show big text on TextField.

Comment: Impossible to say what's wrong without seeing any code/FXML/css.

Comment: @Pagbo Well, I thought that the code is not needed, because it always happens with the usual parameters when text bigger than width. Some example
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    tf.setPrefColumnCount(20);
    tf.setMaxWidth(200);
    bp.setCenter(tf);
    Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 300, 300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    tf.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

Comment: You should edit your post and your code for more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not always occurs. In your example, it happens, because you set the initial text after having shown the stage.

```
public class TextAlign extends Application {

   /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
    */
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

      BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
      TextField tf = new TextField();
      tf.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
      tf.setPrefColumnCount(20);
      tf.setMaxWidth(200);
      // Default text is part of initialization.
      tf.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
      bp.setCenter(tf);
      Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 300, 300);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();

   }
}
```

Moreover if you use FXML (like it is recommanded in JavaFX even if not mandatory), you would not have this behavior as everything is done in the correct order.

**Edit**

From information you add, I would have used `Label` instead of `TextField`. Choose the appropriate `textOverrun` and `ellipsis` if the word is too long, and add a `Tooltip` in order to see the entire Label if needed. Set the label's style in order to get your Label looks like to the wanted TextField (I did not use css for this example, but I should have, if only I was not lazy).

> Controller **TextAlignCtrl.java**

```
public class TextAlignCtrl extends BorderPane {

   @FXML
   private Label summary;

   public TextAlignCtrl() {
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TextAlign.fxml"));
      loader.setController(this);
      loader.setRoot(this);

      try {
         loader.load();
      } catch(IOException e) {
         System.out.println("An error occurs trying to load the FXML TextAlign component." + e);
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   @FXML
   private void initialize() {
      summary.setText("Author - Music Name");
      Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
      tooltip.textProperty().bind(summary.textProperty());
      Tooltip.install(summary, tooltip);
   }

   @FXML
   private void copyTextField(MouseEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Mouse released on label");
   }

   @FXML
   private void selectLabel(MouseEvent e) {
      String lText = ((Label) e.getSource()).getText();
      System.out.println("Label selection " + lText);
      summary.setText(lText);
   }
}
```

> FXML **TextAlign.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root type="BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <left>
        <VBox>
            <HBox>
                <Label fx:id="lbl1" text="U2 - I Still Haven't Found What I'm Looking For"
                    onMouseClicked="#selectLabel" />
            </HBox>
            <HBox>
                <Label fx:id="lbl2" text="Bob Marley - One love"
                    onMouseClicked="#selectLabel" />
            </HBox>
            <HBox>
                <Label fx:id="lbl3" text="Scorpions - Still loving you" onMouseClicked="#selectLabel" />
            </HBox>
            <HBox>
                <Label fx:id="lbl4" text="Queen - We will rock you." onMouseClicked="#selectLabel" />
            </HBox>
        </VBox>
    </left>
    <top>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER">
            <Label fx:id="summary" alignment="CENTER"
                style="-fx-border-color:grey;-fx-border-width:2px;" onMouseReleased="#copyTextField"
                pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="250.0" textOverrun="CENTER_WORD_ELLIPSIS" ellipsisString="[...]" >
                <font>
                    <Font name="Arial" size="16.0" />
                </font>
            </Label>
            <!-- <TextField fx:id="textField" alignment="CENTER" disable="false" editable="true" 
                onMouseReleased="#copyTextField" style="-fx-text-overrun:CENTER;" pickOnBounds="false" 
                prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="250.0" promptText="Author - Music Name" > <font> 
                <Font name="Arial" size="16.0" /> </font> </TextField> -->
        </HBox>
    </top>
</fx:root>
```

> Application Entry Point **MainTextAlign.java**

```
public class MainTextAlign extends Application {

   @FXML
   private TextField tf;

   /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
    */
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

      TextAlignCtrl bp = new TextAlignCtrl();

      Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 300, 300);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }
}
```

[image: short words]
[image: long words]

Comment: This was just an example of the code. I need to change the text of the TextField during the program execution. Also in my real project everything is written in fhml. 
 <TextField alignment="CENTER" editable="false" onMouseReleased="#copyTextField"
              pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="440.0"
              promptText="Author - Music Name" fx:id="textField">
              <font>
                <Font name="Arial" size="16.0" />
              </font>
</TextField>

Comment: @Pagdo yes. Only programm can change text, not user

Comment: @DimaGarbar This is effectively a problem, but I do not think the `TextField` is the best solution. Please have a look on my edit.

Comment: @Pagdo I put it as the correct answer, but I think you understand that TextField does not work as it should.

Comment: @DimaGarbar As I said, it seems to be a problem. But I did not find any documentation about the behavior it should have in this case. Clearly it is linked with the caret, but on another side, `TextField` is dedicated for the user inputs (even if it is possible to display text with it). Then I am wondering if it is worse to open a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you call `appendText("")` or even `end()`:

```
tf.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
tf.appendText("");
// tf.end();
```

then it causes it to update and align properly, just check that there aren't any unintended side effects.

Admittedly, I haven't dug deep enough to find out why this error is happening in the first place but this workaround should suffice for now eh?

Comment: Now this is the best answer. If soon no one answers more precisely what the problem is, then I will close the question.